# Tomcat CentOS log4j2

Tags: java, centos, tomcat, log4j2

На удалённом сервере CentOS по какой-то причине не создаётся папка с логами, и не пишутся сами логи. На локальной машине Win10, всё работает. На удалёнке перед томкатом стоит nginx, есть ли какие-то идеи? 
Вот конфигруационный файл log4j2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log_dir">LOG</Property>
        <Property name="name_file">${date:yyyy_MM_dd}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p %-40.40c %x : %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log_dir}/${name_file}.log"
                     filePattern="${log_dir}/server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}, %r] %c %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <Async name="AsyncFile">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Async>
        <Async name="AsyncConsole">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="AsyncConsole"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cоздайте папку

`<Property name="log_dir">LOG</Property>`

руками и сделайте ее доступной для записи пользователю, под которым бежит Tomcat. Или что-то вроде этого из под рута:

```
chgrp -R tomcat7 /etc/tomcat7
chmod -R g+w /etc/tomcat7
```

`/etc/tomcat7` - это должен путь, куда у вас томкэт установлен. Можно еще `${catalina.base}` использовать как префикс пути в `<Property name="log_dir">`, что бы не гадать, куда это все будет писаться.